# Emails do not filter on visa sponsorship

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, email

I have an email notification set up for visa sponsorship.  Currently it does not filter on that properly; all job postings are returned.  This has been happening since the 18th of December.

[image]

It's the same for the RSS feed: 895 items.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the report, Tjorriemorrie. We released a bug that affected the relevance of the results in our job e-mails and RSS feeds. It got fixed yesterday. That should be the last bad e-mail you get. Sorry for the bug.